# Send an e-mail to PayPal buyer

Tags: email, paypal

I'm introducing PayPal Digital Goods for Express Checkout on a web site. For an user who is logged in, a valid checkout results in an update in the user's profile on the website, which in order allows to access more content.

The owner wants to add support for clients which aren't yet logged in to the web site. We handled this by introducing a landing page with an unique URL, which the user is redirected to after payment and which can be used to create a new account or mark an existing account as paid. If the user doesn't want to do this immediately, the URL of the landing page is persistent and bookmarkable.

However, in case the client doesn't want to log-in immediately and fails to bookmark their unique link, we'd want to additionally send a confirmation e-mail which would contain the link.

Paypal sends a receipt e-mail to the buyer right after purchase. Can I somehow insert additional message for the client in that e-mail?

If not, is there any other PayPal API feature which would let me send a message to the client's e-mail registered with PayPal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able add or modify the content in the email message sent by Paypal.  They lock down those type of things for security purposes.

However, you can send your own confirmation email once you receive notification that the payment has been completed.  Whether you are using PHP or another server side language, you should be able to collect the email address from the variables returned by PayPal and send a custom email using the ***mail*** function.  Since you create a custom landing page for the user, you can simply send it from here.

Comment: I got confused by the docs for some reason and thought that PayPal doesn't disclose the client's e-mail to me. I've double-checked and yes, the e-mail is in the response for `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`. That solves the problem, thanks!