# Send email after PayPal Purchase

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a form on Booking process page of my website. Below that form I have a PayPal button that leads to PayPal payment page. I'm passing few values like: price, name of tour and currency to PayPal regardless of that form that I've mentioned.

That form above PayPal button needs to be filled in and then user should click on PayPal button. After that he needs to make a payment on PayPal. That's working!

Now, I need, when the payment is over, from PayPal to send back variables from that form on some page of my website from which I could send PHP email containing those values.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a similar thing a while ago. Not a 100% similar, but maybe you'll find this useful:

[Send an e-mail to PayPal buyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851084/send-an-e-mail-to-paypal-buyer)

http://imsolutionsgroup.com/learn-how-to-automatically-add-a-paypal-buyer-to-your-email-autoresponder

http://blog.mailchimp.com/paypal-add-on-for-mailchimp/

http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-api-class/20